# Plotly addTraces/relayout giving different output than newPlot

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a simple plot with two traces and two yaxis specs. When I plot them at the same time using `newPlot` I get the desired result. When I plot the traces (and layouts) one at a time, I get a different result, which is not what I want.

With `newPlot`

[image]

With `addTraces`/`relayout`

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/eatszatj/

Javascript:

```
Plotly.newPlot("graph",[{}],{title: "Plot"});

trace1 = {y: [1,2,1]};
trace2 = {
    y: [0,0,0], 
  yaxis: "y2", 
  mode: "markers", 
  marker: {symbol: 6, size: 12}
};
yaxis1 = {domain: [0, 0.8], title: "one"};
yaxis2 = {
    domain: [0.85, 1.0],
  showgrid: false,
  showticklabels: false,
  title: "two",
  zeroline: false
};

Plotly.addTraces('graph', [trace1]);
Plotly.relayout('graph', {yaxis1});

Plotly.addTraces('graph', [trace2]);
Plotly.relayout('graph', {yaxis2});

//Plotly.newPlot('graph',[trace1, trace2],{yaxis1, yaxis2});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that you need to call `relayout` before `addTraces`. Ettiene (etpinard) found me this solution for a different issue.

http://community.plot.ly/t/no-2nd-y-axis-with-addtraces-and-relayout/963

And it solved this one as well.

```
Plotly.newPlot("graph",[],{title: "Plot"});

trace1 = {y: [1,2,1]};
trace2 = {
    y: [0,0,0], 
  yaxis: "y2", 
  mode: "markers", 
  marker: {symbol: 6, size: 12}
};
yaxis1 = {domain: [0, 0.8], title: "one"};
yaxis2 = {
    domain: [0.85, 1.0],
  showgrid: false,
  showticklabels: false,
  title: "two",
  zeroline: false
};

Plotly.relayout('graph', {yaxis1});
Plotly.addTraces('graph', [trace1]);

Plotly.relayout('graph', {yaxis2});
Plotly.addTraces('graph', [trace2]);

//Plotly.newPlot('graph',[trace1, trace2],{yaxis1, yaxis2});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your first `Plotly.newPlot` call. You're passing in a empty trace object which is defaulted to a invisible scatter trace.

This implies that the trace in your first `Plotly.addTraces` call is in fact the graph's second trace (drawn in orange by default) and the trace in your second `Plotly.addTraces` call is in fact the graph's third trace (drawn in green by default).

So, by changing your first line to

```
Plotly.newPlot("graph",[],{title: "Plot"});
```

you'll get the desired resulting plot.

Comment: Oh, interesting...such a subtle point. However, I created a new fiddle with that adjustment, and the problem remains.https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/1y4chsu7/

Comment: I don't see a problem in your updated fiddle. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, must have forgotten to hit update before I closed the tab. Look now... https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/eatszatj/