# Dynamically create subplots with Plotly in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm attempting to use Plotly to create an R Shiny app that dynamically populates a set of subplots sharing an x axis. Each subplot corresponds to a unique value in the data's `UserID` column. The code in question:

```
valid.directories <- get.valid.directories()
num.ids <- length(valid.directories)
# for subplot domain scaling
fraction <- 100 / num.ids

output[["plot1"]] <- renderPlotly({
    # populate first subplot
    p <- plot_ly(selected.data(), x = Timestamp[which(as.integer(valid.directories[1]) == as.integer(UserID))], y = Name[which(as.integer(valid.directories[1]) == as.integer(UserID))], xaxis = "x1", yaxis = "y1", mode = "markers")
    # accumulate arguments for layout call
    args.names <- c("showlegend", "xaxis", "yaxis")
    for (i in 2:num.ids) {
        args.names <- c(args.names, paste0("yaxis", i))
    }
    args <- vector("list", length(args.names))
    names(args) <- args.names
    args[["showlegend"]] <- FALSE
    args[["xaxis"]] <- list(title = "")
    args[["yaxis"]] <- list(anchor = 'x', domain = c(0, (fraction - (fraction / 10)) / 100), title = valid.directories[1])
    for (j in 2:num.ids) {
        p <- add_trace(p, x = Timestamp[which(as.integer(valid.directories[j]) == as.integer(UserID))], y = Name[which(as.integer(valid.directories[j]) == as.integer(UserID))], xaxis = "x1", yaxis = paste0("y", j), mode = "markers")
        if (j == num.ids) {
            last.upper.bound <- 1
        } else {
            last.upper.bound <- (fraction * j - (fraction / 10)) / 100
        }
        args[[paste0("yaxis", j)]] <- list(anchor = 'x', domain = c((fraction * (j - 1) + (fraction / 10)) / 100, last.upper.bound), title = valid.directories[j])
    }
    # populate additional subplots
    p <- do.call(layout, c(p, args))
    p
})
```

It almost works, but only the first and last subplots are populated correctly. Interior subplots appear, but do not display any data and their y axis domains are 0-4 instead of the correct values, AC, EOD and RT. I've checked that the underlying data is not the problem. Here's a screenshot of the incorrect plot:

[image: incorrect]

And this one shows the same data plotted correctly on entirely separate plots:

[image: correct]

I've been unable to figure out why the interior subplots are not shown correctly. The last subplot (9999) is populated in the same loop as the interior ones, but it is correct. I've verified that `last.upper.bound`, which is different for the last subplot, is not the issue.

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably just use `ggplot2::facet_grid` and `plotly::ggplotly`, though it gives you a different style.

Comment: If you did what @alistaire suggested you can just restyle the ggplot before conversion with `ggplotly`

Comment: I'm having similar problems, and it has to do with the "overlay" attribute in the yaxes. You also need to make sure you associate each trace with a y-axis. EXCEPT that in the traces you call them "y", "y2", "y3", while in the layout, the same axes are "yaxis", "yaxis2", "yaxis3", etc. If you go to the plotly forum, or search around on SO you can find my posts with partial solutions.

Comment: @zacdav @alistaire@abalter  thanks.. I renamed things and call layout before adding traces as per your solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974231/plotly-addtraces-relayout-giving-different-output-than-newplot) and have not gotten it to work. `facet_grid` with ggplotly is doing the trick